# Как правильно использовать пакет "flag" в Golang

Tags: golang

Задача реализовать пакет **flag**. На вывод есть готовый стринг, в аргумент передается значение
**--color=<color>** и вместо **<color>** могут написать любой цвет.И суть задачи готовый стринг покрасить в ранее написанный цвет.

*Пример:*  `go run . text --color=red`

*Должен выдать:* text в красном цвете [в терминале VS Code]

*Мой вопрос:*
Если я буду искать название цвета в аругменте через **regex**, и значения **regex**  передам в переменную **s**, то могу ли в синтаксисе **flag** в место "String" передать переменную **s**, что бы **s** сравнить в цикле с названиями цветами, что бы в текст передать нужный цвет.У меня уже есть набор цвет[например:`red := "\033[31m"`]

`c := flag.String("nameOfFlag", "String", "Usage String")`

Большая просьба не писать сразу готовый код,а направить подсказками.

Comment: вам лучше сделать map типа var colorsMap map[string]string, где в ключ поставить название цвета, а в значение - его код.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov Да у меня в мыслях были создать мапу как вы говорите,но потом мне надо будет как то сравнить ключ мапы с тем что ввели в аргумент.

Comment: Map может быть использована как обычный массив, по которому можно пройтись и делать трансформацию ключа или значения по необходимости. Вполне можно сделать for mapKey, mapValue := range colorsMap { if strings.ToLower(mapKey) == strings.ToLower(flagInputValue) {} }